Polynomials of arbitrary degree with at most 3 real roots
Playing around with polynomials of the form $ax^n(1-x)+b(1-x)-2$ it seems that they have at most 3 real roots, for any value of $(a,b)$ and any natural $n$.
How to prove this?

What if $a,b$ are rationals & $n$ is even degree

@Guruprasad 0 is at most 3. 2 is also at most 3. I don't understand your concern.

I mean, it is possible to construct counter example

@Guruprasad please show me this counterexample

@Guruprasad  OP is making a claim that there are at most 3 real roots. $\quad$ If you can find a polynomial of that form with 4 real roots, then yes it is a valid counter example to OP's claim. (In which case, OP might want to increase the cutoff).

The claim is false; $n=7, a=100, b=2$ gives a function with 4 roots. We can show this is maximal as follows:
If $f$ is the polynomial then $f'(x)= - a x^{n-1} ((n-1)x-n)-b$, and $f''(x)= -a n x^{n-2} ((n+1)x+1-n)$.
If $a=0$ then the $f$ is linear so we're done. Otherwise $f''$ has at most $2$ roots (since $x^{n-2}$ and $(n+1)x+1-n$ both have at most $1$), so $f$ has at most 4 roots.

Excellent. Thanks. Actually, I forgot to say I was interested in positive roots. Can we say something about that?

By Descartes' rule of signs it's at most 3 (since we only have 4 terms in the polynomial), and that can be achieved by setting n=7,a=100, and b=3

How did you construct counter example ?

@Guruprasad Just played around with desmos until it worked. I immediately got something where the second derivative had 2 roots, and since b is the constant term in the derivative I could change it until the derivative had 3 roots. Then I noticed that increasing a "stretched" the graph vertically, so I tried a=100 and it worked

You saved my time. I also tried to construct counter example
